# How to specify a column to order by in a parameter to a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure to return the top 50 rows from a table, like this:

```
select top 50 
    Puzzle, 
    min(DateSolved) as CreationDate, 
    avg(SecondsToComplete) as AverageTime, 
    count(*) as TimesSolved 
  from CustomSolves
  group by Puzzle
```

But I want the stored procedure to accept two parameters, so that I can order by a custom column (the creation date, the average time, or the times sovled) and only select records newer than a certain date. Something like this pseudo-SQL:

```
procedure SelectCustomPuzzles
  @CutoffDate datetime,
  @SortColumn column
as
  select top 50 
      Puzzle, 
      min(DateSolved) as CreationDate, 
      avg(SecondsToComplete) as AverageTime, 
      count(*) as TimesSolved 
    from CustomSolves
    where CreationDate > @CutOffDate
    group by Puzzle
    order by @SortColumn
```

How could I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
order by 
   CASE @SortColumn WHEN 'foo ASC' THEN foo ELSE NULL END,
   CASE @SortColumn WHEN 'foo DESC' THEN foo ELSE NULL END DESC,
   CASE @SortColumn WHEN 'bar ASC' THEN bar ELSE NULL END,
   CASE @SortColumn WHEN 'bar DESC' THEN bar ELSE NULL END DESC,
```

Edit, for a default sort add one of these

```
...
CASE  WHEN @SortColumn IS NULL THEN default ELSE NULL END DESC

...
defautcolumn
```

Notes:

- ASC or DESC can't be in the CASE: has to be outside
- A single CASE with multiple `WHEN..THEN column` requires datatypes to be implicitly CASTable. I prefer separate CASE expressions to avoid implicit conversions See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4166/630 for a worked example

Comment: How do I do a default case, in case the sort column doesn't match any of the cases?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `case`:

```
order by case when @SortColumn = 'Puzzle' then Puzzle end,
         case when @SortColumn = 'PuzzleDesc' then Puzzle end desc,
         ...
```

The database can't use indexes if you write the query like this.  The only way around that is dynamic SQL, like:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select * from tbl1 order by ' + @OrderByVar
exec @sql
```

Comment: Edited... you could omit `else null` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are willing to go into dynamic SQL territory (which would likely be an overkill for something like an `order by`) consider using `case-when`:

```
order by case(@SortColumn)
    when 'ColumnName2' then ColumnName1
    when 'ColumnName2' then ColumnName2
    else ColumnName3
end
```

As gbn noted below, this would work only because your three sort columns are of the same type. Had it not been like that, you'd need to add a cast (perhaps to `sql_variant`) in order for the SQL server to accept your query.

Comment: Should be noted that this requires column datatypes to be compatible. http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4166/630

Comment: @gbn Thanks for the note! I edited the answer to suggest a work-around.